# Finding normalised eigenvectors...

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to find the eigenvector/eigenvalues of the $2\times2$ matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}

This is my work:

$$\det(A-\lambda I) = \lambda^2-7 \lambda+8=0 \iff \lambda=\frac{7+\sqrt{17}}{2} \ \lor \ \lambda= \frac{7-\sqrt{17}}{2}$$

$x_1$ (eigenvector)=\begin{pmatrix} (1+\sqrt17)/4 \\ k  \end{pmatrix} , where k is any number. How do I "NORMALISE" this eigenvector?
Can someone check my working because I'm getting weird answers.

Comment: I can't read this, please visit the latex manual to make this readable, and edit your post. For now I'll edit what i think to understand.

Comment: Your eigenvector should have 2 elements, not just one.

Comment: @Anon Perhaps if you explain from where you get $\begin{pmatrix} (1+\sqrt17)/4 \\ k  \end{pmatrix}$, you might get a better explanation why it is incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

If $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$ and $(A-\lambda I)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$.

First, find the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $λ=\frac{7+\sqrt{17}}{2}$:

$$\begin{align*} &\quad\quad\quad\quad\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
A-\lambda I & 0
\end{array}\right)\quad\quad\text{insert your }A\text{ and }\lambda\\ &=\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
4-\tfrac{7+\sqrt{17}}{2} & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 3-\tfrac{7+\sqrt{17}}{2} & 0
\end{array}\right)\quad\quad\text{compute the differences}\\ &\implies \left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
\tfrac{1-\sqrt{17}}{2} & 2 & 0 \\
2 & \tfrac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2} & 0
\end{array}\right)\quad\quad\text{multiply the first row by }\tfrac{4}{1-\sqrt{17}}\\ &\implies \left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
2 & \tfrac{8}{1-\sqrt{17}} & 0 \\
2 & \tfrac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2} & 0
\end{array}\right)\quad\quad\text{multiply the first fraction by }1+\sqrt{17}\\ &\implies \left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
2 & \tfrac{8(1+\sqrt{17})}{-16} & 0 \\
2 & \tfrac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2} & 0
\end{array}\right)\quad\quad\text{simplify the first fraction}\\ &\implies \left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
2 & \tfrac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2} & 0 \\
2 & \tfrac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2} & 0
\end{array}\right)\quad\quad\text{subtract the first row from the second}\\ &\implies \left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
4 & -1-\sqrt{17} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\quad\quad\text{deduce the solution}\\ &\implies \mathbf{x}=k\pmatrix{1+\sqrt{17}\\4}\end{align*}$$

Now, normalize it by

$$\hat{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{\mathbf{x}}{||\mathbf{x}||}$$

and do the same thing for the second eigenvalue.

Comment: Could you explain your steps please.

Comment: @Anon I have added some explanation. Please, ask if something remains unclear.

Comment: I don't understand this we have not been taught this notation...

Comment: @Anon I have used [augmented matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix). There is an example at the end of the article.

Comment: I need to do it the way I was taught in lectures though and we didn't use augmented matrices to do it please help I'm so confused. Souldn't your last line have a -1 instead of +1 too?

Answer (score 4):

HINT: normalized vector $\vec n$ from given vector $\vec v$ can be found with this formula:
$$\vec n=\frac{\vec v}{||\vec v||}$$
where $||\vec v||=\sqrt{\vec v\cdot\vec v}$ is the norm of $\vec v$.

Comment: When I try this k comes out as a complex number!? Have you actually tryed this?

Comment: How come you are trying to get $k$ when you should get a vector corresponding to your source $\vec x_1$? $k$ should be a parameter here.

Comment: I thought to normalise the vector its modulus should equal 1 so I need a k that makes that happen...

Comment: Well, then you are not trying to normalize a given vector, but instead find $k$ so that its norm appears 1. Looks like you've misformulated your problem.

Comment: So how do I "Normalise" the eigenvector?! Question says find normalised eigenvectors of matrix shown above.

Comment: Find its norm, then solve $||\vec x_1||=1$ to find $k$.

Comment: Thats what I just did!!! It comes out complex I think can you tell me what you get? I got k = (1/8 + sqrt17/8)i

Comment: Yes, that's OK that $k$ appears complex, because $\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}>1$. In fact, your way of finding the eigenvector is not completely understandable. Why should $k$ be any number? Your $x_1$ will be an eigenvector only for one $k$.

Comment: I really have no idea I'm a chemistry student I just copy what my maths lecturer does...

Comment: See the answer by Tharsis. It should be better to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors+%5b%5b4%2C2%5d%2C%5b2%2C3%5d%5d) to check your result.

I wanted to mention, that it is often useful to apply what you know about eigenvalues; you can use $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=7$, $\lambda_1\lambda_2=-8$, $\lambda_1^2-7\lambda_1+8=0$ when trying to solve the system.

For example:
$A-\lambda_1 I=
\begin{pmatrix}
4-\lambda_1 & 2 \\
2 & 3-\lambda_1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
4-\lambda_1 & 2 \\
2 & 3-\lambda_1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
12-7\lambda_1+\lambda_1^2 & 2(3-\lambda_1)\\
2 & 3-\lambda_1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2(3-\lambda_1)\\
2 & 3-\lambda_1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3-\lambda_1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$
(Note that if you are using row vectors, you would transpose the matrix $A-\lambda I$ to get the linear system you have to solve. But from your post it seems that you are using column vectors.)

Comment: What does this symbol $\sim$ mean here?  Does that mean $\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2(3-\lambda_1)\\
2 & 3-\lambda_1
\end{pmatrix}\sim$ is not exactly equal to $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3-\lambda_1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @baojieqh The symbol $\sim$ stands for [row equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_equivalence) of matrices.